# Generating non-compatible certificate with a CA

Tags: c#, x509, private-key, public-key, certenroll

I'm using this stretch of code to create a request, which will be sent to validation in my CA, but when arrives there is denied:

Using:

- .NET framework 3.5
- Is a Dll project
- IIS 6.0
- CertEnroll.dll
- There is no possibility to update technology

  ```
  [ComVisible(true), Description("Create User Key Pair")]
  public String CreateBase64KeyPair(string CN)
  {
      string msg = string.Empty;

      try
      {
          CX509CertificateRequestCertificate objPkcs10 = (CX509CertificateRequestCertificate)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestCertificate"));
          IX509PrivateKey objPrivateKey = (IX509PrivateKey)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey"));
          CCspInformation objCSP = (CCspInformation)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CCspInformation"));
          CCspInformations objCSPs = (CCspInformations)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CCspInformations"));
          CX500DistinguishedName objDN = (CX500DistinguishedName)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CX500DistinguishedName"));
          CX509Enrollment objEnroll = (CX509Enrollment)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment"));
          CObjectIds objObjectIds = (CObjectIds)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CObjectIds"));
          CObjectId objObjectId = (CObjectId)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CObjectId"));
          CX509ExtensionKeyUsage objExtensionKeyUsage = (CX509ExtensionKeyUsage)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CX509ExtensionKeyUsage"));
          CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage = (CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("X509Enrollment.CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage"));


          //  Initialize the csp object using the desired Cryptograhic Service Provider (CSP)
          objCSP.InitializeFromName(YPSIDCSP_NAME);
          //  Add this CSP object to the CSP collection object
          objCSPs.Add(objCSP);                
          //Provide key container name, key length and key spec to the private key object
          objPrivateKey.Length = 1024; //KEY_LEN_MY_DEFAULT
          objPrivateKey.ProviderType = X509ProviderType.XCN_PROV_RSA_FULL; //XEnroll.ProviderType=1
          objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE; //XEnroll.KeySpec=AT_KEYEXCHANGE
          objPrivateKey.KeyUsage = X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_ALL_USAGES;
          objPrivateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG;
          objPrivateKey.MachineContext = false;
          //  Provide the CSP collection object (in this case containing only 1 CSP object) to the private key object
          objPrivateKey.CspInformations = objCSPs;
          //  Create the actual key pair
          objPrivateKey.Create();

          //  Initialize the PKCS#10 certificate request object based on the private key.
          //  Using the context, indicate that this is a user certificate request and don’t provide a template name
          objPkcs10.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, objPrivateKey, string.Empty);

          // Key Usage Extension
          objExtensionKeyUsage.InitializeEncode(
              CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE |
              CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE |
              CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DATA_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE|
              CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_NON_REPUDIATION_KEY_USAGE
          );

          objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objExtensionKeyUsage);

          // Enhanced Key Usage Extension
          objObjectId.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"); // OID for Client Authentication usage

          objObjectIds.Add(objObjectId);

          objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage.InitializeEncode(objObjectIds);


          objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage);


          //  Encode the name in using the Distinguished Name object
          //TODO: TDSiS: Validar essa questão da CN
          objDN.Encode("CN="+ CN.Trim(), X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);

          //  Assing the subject name by using the Distinguished Name object initialized above
          objPkcs10.Subject = objDN;

          // Create enrollment request
          objEnroll.InitializeFromRequest(objPkcs10);

          return objEnroll.CreateRequest(EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          return ex.Message;
      }
  }
  ```

any doubts about the specifications, just tell me.

Thank you in advance for help! :)

Comment: *Why* is it denied? It's up to the CA to decide why a request is not valid. It could be a missing template, for example.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but doing `ex.ToString()` instead of `ex.Message` will give you a lot more useful information. For example if you have a inner exception `ex.Message` won't show the info but `ex.ToString()` will.

Comment: @vcsjones log: Erro: CCertRequest::Submit The data is invalid. 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13). This is the error that show to me in log.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks i will change that :) tks.